# Sun folder is not created while installing jdk 1.7

Tags: java

In my system sun folder is not created in C:\windows folder in windows 7 OS while installing jdk 1.7. I have administrative rights for system.

Comment: Eh, usually the installer let you specify the installation directory. If you did not change the default settings, the JDK will be in C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.[your_version_here]. No sun folder is created. Java is now owned by Oracle, btw.

Comment: of course your are correct but in some of my friends machines who have admin rights sun folder is present under C:\windows\sun and deployment folder is available under the sun folder

Comment: Maybe they have installed another product. I have checked my computer and you're right, I got an empty folder C:\Windows\Sun\Java\Deployment but I don't know exactly how it was created. Maybe it's a temporal folder. I think that you can use the JDK without it.

Comment: this is the exact problem i am facing. any help from ur side

Answer (score 0):

There should be `Java` folder in your `C` drive not the `Sun` folder. Look at the path

```
C:\Program Files\Java
```

In the Java folder there are two folder **`1`** you are looking for `jdk` and other `jre`.

Comment: of course your are correct but in some of my friends machines who have admin rights sun folder is present under C:\windows\sun and deployment folder is available under the sun folder

Comment: are they using `windows` system ?

Comment: Yes same configuration windows 7 with 64 bit i struggled for 3 days but not got any solutions :(